# ScrollListener code not working as intended when user stutter swipes on RecyclerView + PagerSnapHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm attempting to change the date in the AppBar whenever a user swipes left or right (Left to go down one day; right to go up one day). Currently I have a ScrollListener with the following code:

```
int scrollDirection = 0;               //-1 is left ; 1 is right

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dx > 0) {
                scrollDirection = 1;
            }

            if (dx < 0) {
                scrollDirection = -1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                if (scrollDirection == 1) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }

                if (scrollDirection == -1) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                }

                setCurrentDate(cal.getTime());
            }

        }
```

Now this works fine under normal circumstances, but if a user stutter swipes (swipes half way to the next view and then releases causing the PagerSnapHelper to snap back to the original view) then the date changes while the view stays the same.

The PagerSnapHelper is working as intended, the issue lies with the code registering the scroll state as settling without the view changing, thus the date is changing. I'm looking for a way to detect if the view being presented is actually a new view or the previous view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the recommended approaches but there were still frequent issues with the functionality. For example, if I swiped through two pages before android considered the recyclerView to be IDLE then the date would not update correctly.

Upon looking at how similar issues were resolved, I decided to change the date based on how many screen lengths I've moved over since one of my views in the recyclerView is exactly one screen width. Below is my solution

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int width = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int daysToBeAdded;
        int totalDX;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            totalDX+= dx;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                daysToBeAdded = totalDX / width;
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToBeAdded);
                setCurrentDate(cal.getTime());
                totalDX = 0;
            }

        }
    });
```